# How to load different scripts for different versions of IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, conditional-comments

I use [these scripts](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to repair the errors in IE (Hacks).

There is one for each version.

> I know that everything has IE9.js IE8 and 7 but would like to load
>   only the necessary script to that version of the browser;

**Today my code is as follows:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IE7.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ie7-squish.js")"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IE8.js")">IE7_PNG_SUFFIX=".png";</script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ie7-squish.js")"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IE9.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ie7-squish.js")"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I would not like to use something like `<!--[if eq IE 8]>` because I do not know how it would behave in such versions as IE8.5.

I do not know if there is `else`, I searched the internet and did not see anyone commenting on this. But it would be the ideal solution.

**Something like this:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IE7.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ie7-squish.js")"></script>
<![elseif lt IE 8]-->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IE8.js")">IE7_PNG_SUFFIX=".png";</script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ie7-squish.js")"></script>
<![elseif lt IE 9]-->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IE9.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ie7-squish.js")"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think that's how those scripts work. Your supposed to include IE9.js in all those browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment.
IE9.js be included in IE8 and 7. It's not what I want.
I want to be included IE9.js only in  IE9 the same for the other scripts.

Comment: This post also deals with this question[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226288/if-condition-if-the-browser-is-ie-and-ie-browser-version-is-older-than-9/25254666#25254666][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226288/if-condition-if-the-browser-is-ie-and-ie-browser-version-is-older-than-9/25254666#25254666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You do not need to include IE7/IE8.js if you are using IE9.js

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IE9.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ie7-squish.js")"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Problem solved.

Comment: OK, I know that, in the question I talked about this:
"I know, `IE9.js` has included IE8 and 7 but would like to load only the necessary script to that version of the browser"

In other words, I want to load only the JS related to that version of IE

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa I can't think of any good reason to want to do that? Can you explain _why_ you only want to include ie7.js in IE7 ?

Comment: Because of conflicts. No sense in applying the IE7 hacks in IE8 for exemple.
Of course, if not have a solution I will have to use the IE9.js.
This is just a question I had while studying hacks in IE

Comment: In the post.  http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/ie7_script.html check this note:  "Note: Of course when you use any of the scripts you ned to include only the highest you wish to apply."

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa that's not how it works, IE9.js does useful fixes in all the browsers.